# Renaming table in Directus CMS

Tags: content-management-system, headless, directus

How can I rename a table in "Directus" CMS(https://getdirectus.com)?

I tried renaming the name from the admin portal but it does not work. There is a clear messages written under the "name":

> Can not (currently) be changed within the CMS.

[Directus table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEKef.png)

Is there any workaround to change it?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way to rename a table in Directus version 6.x. This is because the table name would also need to be updated throughout many instances within Settings. Version 7.0 (release in Q2-2018) will have the ability to rename tables and the update will cascade throughout the system.

For now, you can manually make this change directly in the database. First, update the actual table name, then change any references to it within `idrectus_tables`, `directus_columns` and `directus_privileges`. You can also update `directus_activity`, but only if you need to maintain existing revisions/history for that table.

Comment: Still not sure how to do this today.
Any info?